# What are the reasons for not wearing polarized glasses during flying, if glass cockpit and polarized windshield aren't an issue?

Tags: equipment, night-flying, glass-cockpit

So far the only reasons I can find are the newer planes come with polarized windshields that goes dark when you wear polarized glasses and the fact that glass cockpits become dark.

But is there a single reason to not wear polarized glasses while flying something like an vintage J3 Cub with nothing but some gauges etc? Can you see the PAPI lights and other necessary stuff? What keeps an pilot from wearing polarized glasses?

Comment: LC displays should be the only problem. Why are you asking in the first place? Have you been told not to wear polarizing glasses in the cockpit?

Comment: @bogl The multiple sources on the net says it keeps you from seeing the screens and breaks your vision when coupled with ann polarzied cockpit  glass and I wondered whetever there were other problems etc.

Comment: It's not the windows, it's the instruments.  I notice this even in my car now, tilting your  head and the two polarizations make screens go dark.  Need to find my RayBan unpolarized glasses now that I've gone to electronic screens for moving map GPS and attitude indicator. The old vacuum driven gyros didn't have that issue.

Comment: Glass cockpit actually refers to electronic displays, not to the wind shield. Possibly that is a source of confusion?

Comment: Been wearing them off and on for... well, several decades since I took my first lesson.  No problems.  But I don't really use anything with electronic displays.

Comment: I wear polarized sunglasses when flying, but I specifically chose my frames so the instrument panel would be mostly *beneath* the lenses instead of *to* them because it's a lot darker inside; I didn't even think about polarization. No problems with glass so far.

Comment: @StephenS did you ever think about wearing gradient glasses?

Comment: @bogl according to some video I watched. The windshield in a prop plane got distorted colors and darkness all over when filmed through polarized lenses and I first noticed LCD weirdness when I tried to watch TV with my sunglasses.

Comment: @JonathanIrons Never heard of that until now. I think I'd need bifocals for it to work since my near vision doesn't need correction (yet), so it's simpler to just get lenses I can see under for close/dark things. Works well in the car too. Not so good for walking around, but better than nothing.